# Evaluating $\int_0^{2\pi} \sqrt{1+\cos(t)} \ \mathrm{d}t$

Tags: calculus, differential-geometry

Context: I'm trying to evaluate the total  length of the following curve:
$\gamma: (0,2\pi) \to \mathbb{R^2}, \gamma(t)=\bigg(t+\sin(t), 1-\cos(t)\bigg)$.

$$\underline{\text{My working}}$$
$$\begin{align}s=\int_0^{2\pi}|\gamma'(t)| \ \mathrm{d}t&=\int_0^{2\pi} \sqrt{\left[1+\cos(t)\right]^2+\sin^2(t)} \ \mathrm{d}t \\ \ \\&=\int_0^{2\pi} \sqrt{1+2\cos(t)+\cos^2(t)+\sin^2(t)} \ \mathrm{d}t \\ \ \\&=\int_0^{2\pi} \sqrt{2+2\cos(t)} \ \mathrm{d} t\\ \ \\&=\sqrt{2} \int_0^{2\pi}\sqrt{1+\cos(t)} \ \mathrm{d}t \\ \ \\&=??\end{align}$$

Any ideas on a suitable substitution?

Comment: use that $\cos(x)=2\cos(x/2)^2-1$

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use the trigonometric identity

$$1 + \cos t = (\cos^2 \tfrac{t}{2} + \sin^2 \tfrac{t}{2}) + (\cos^2\tfrac{t}{2} - \sin^2 \tfrac{t}{2}) = 2 \cos^2 \tfrac{t}{2}.$$

Comment: Awesome! But how would I then evaluate $\int_0^{2\pi} |\cos(t/2)|\mathrm{d} t$ (the absolute value is throwing me off)?

Comment: Use the symmetry, $$\int_0^{2\pi} \lvert \cos (t/2)\rvert\,dt = 2\int_0^\pi \lvert \cos u\rvert\,du = 4\int_0^{\pi/2}\lvert\cos u\rvert\,du = 4\int_0^{\pi/2}\cos u\,du = 4.$$

Answer (score 4):

An alternate method (which is not as simple as using the half-angle formula) is to multiply by $\sqrt{1-\cos t}$ on the top and bottom to get

$\displaystyle\sqrt{2}\int_{0}^{2\pi}\frac{\left|\sin t \right|}{\sqrt{1-\cos t}} dt=\sqrt{2}\left[\int_{0}^{\pi}\frac{\sin t}{\sqrt{1-\cos t}}dt+\int_{\pi}^{2\pi}\frac{-\sin t}{\sqrt{1-\cos t}} dt\right]$

$\;\;\;\displaystyle=\sqrt{2}\left(\left[2\sqrt{1-\cos t}\right]_{0}^{\pi}-[2\sqrt{1-\cos t}]_{\pi}^{2\pi}\right)=\sqrt{2}(2\sqrt{2}-(-2\sqrt{2}))=8.$

(Notice that there are removable discontinuities at the endpoints.)